# ActiveRecord Recover associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have an app which models companies that have users who can even have meals.

So I have a Company table, a User table and a Lunch table.
The lunch contains the id of the user, and the user contains the id of the company. I'd like to get all the lunches available for the `current_user.company`

I'd like to have something like `Lunch.all.where(user.company == current_user.company)`. I know this won't work, but I've just started out and I'm having a little trouble with sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Lunch.joins(user: :company).where(users: {company: current_user.company})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `#joins`, or there's an easier way. Set this up in your Company model

```
class Company
  has_many :users,
  has_many :lunches, through: :users
end
```

And you get all the lunches:

```
current_user.company.lunches
```

Comment: I have this mistake with your solution.

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "lunch" or :lunches in model User. Try 'has_many :lunches, :through => :users, :source => <name>'. Is it one of company, lunchs, or commands?

Comment: yes but with a spelling mistake (lunchs => lunches), now it works, thank you too, I'll see which one has the best response time. but thank you very much; -)

Comment: There is virtually no difference between these two approaches. With ':through' option Rails add an instance method '#lunches'  to Company. But behind the scenes they execute the same SQL. This just makes life easier and makes it less likely to have bugs.

Comment: All right, I prefer this method which is simpler, thank you.